# Popover with form - hover on suggestions (IE Bug)

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer

I have a big problem. At the top I have a button and if you hover on it, you will get the popover. Now you click on the input and get the suggestions.

When you hover at one suggestion in IE 9, then the popover lose his focus / the hover and I must hover again on the button to get the popover.

Any ideas or solutions for it?

```
<div class="has-layer">
  <a href="">Fachpartner-Portal</a>
  <div class="popover"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.has-layer .popover {
  display: none;
}
.has-layer a:hover + .popover {
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

**It works in all modern browser. Only IE-Problem.**

Comment: Do you have styles related to focus?

Comment: I have no styles for elements related to focus.

Answer (score 0):

When i read '*It works in all modern browser. Only IE-Problem*'  i think to myself : This design is buggy and on Internet Explorer doesn't re-write it.

How do you expect your element to be trigered on the anchor:hover  if that element is NOT inside the anchor ?

As soon has the pointer leaves the anchor, (moving to the other container), the css behaves correctly.

Try another design :

```
<div class="has-layer">
    <a href="">Fachpartner-Portal
        <div class="popover"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```